# Cant get past 429 Error (too many requests) on instagram api login (instagrapi)

Tags: python, instagram, httpresponse, instagram-api, response-headers

I need help figuring out the Retry-After time dynamically for my login request to the Instagram API. I am wondering if my IP has been banned on my desktop, however I do not think that is the issue considering it doesnt work when trying the call on my phone/laptop either. I also tried logging into a different instagram account but that gave me the same error. Given these it makes me believe it is something in the code itself and not with my accounts

My story_upload function, it is only called once so it should not be overloading the server:

```
 def upload_post():
      cl = Client()
      cl.login("username", "password")
      image_path = "/home/Spotify365/mysite/static/images/testing.png"
      cl.photo_upload_to_story(path=image_path, caption="Generated Automatically by Spotify365", links=[StoryLink(webUri='https://spotify365.pythonanywhere.com/')])
```

Full error log: (Successful until it tries logging into the API, raises error 429)

```
2021-04-01 12:52:15,655: username [200] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/contact_point_prefill/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,711: username [200] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/get_prefill_candidates/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,747: username [200] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/contact_point_prefill/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,800: username [200] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/launcher/sync/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,878: username [200] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/qe/sync/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,982: username [429] POST https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/ (169.3.0.30.135, Xiaomi capricorn)
2021-04-01 12:52:15,982: Status 429: Too many requests
2021-04-01 12:52:15,983: Exception on /instaStory [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 183, in _send_private_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: - for url: https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/accounts/login/
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/Spotify365/mysite/flask_app.py", line 50, in isStory
    upload_post()
  File "/home/Spotify365/mysite/flask_app.py", line 43, in upload_post
    cl.login("username", "password")
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/auth.py", line 341, in login
    if self.private_request("accounts/login/", data, login=True):
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 316, in private_request
    raise e
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 303, in private_request
    self._send_private_request(endpoint, **kwargs)
  File "/home/Spotify365/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instagrapi/mixins/private.py", line 244, in _send_private_request
    raise PleaseWaitFewMinutes(e, response=e.response, **last_json)
instagrapi.exceptions.PleaseWaitFewMinutes: Please wait a few minutes before you try again.
```

I tried calling jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders() in order to hopefully get the 'Retry-After' header but that didnt really help me:

```
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 290
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 13:13:42 GMT
server: PythonAnywhere
```

Answer (score -2):

429 Error fixed in instagrapi 1.7.0